# How to show numpy NxM array with dtype=float as plain gray scale image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

When creating an `numpy` array with `dtype=float`, the the presentation method using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` appears to be dependent on the values, so a value of 0.50 is not just 50% gray.

Using this code template:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = np.empty([2, 2])
img[:] = {image}
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Then the image `[[1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.5]]` shows as:

[image]

But the image `[[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.5]]`, where only 0.0 is changed to 1.0,  shows as:

[image]

I had expected that the 0.5 (at lower right) would show as 50% gray in both cases, but for some reason the presentation method changes, so 0.5 is interpreted differently, depending on the value of other elements in the array.

So, how to show numpy NxM array with dtype=float as plain gray scale image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to fix the limits of the color-scale:

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray',clim=(0,1))
```

To get a good feeling of what is going on you could include a colorbar which visualizes the conversion between colors and numerical values; for example using the following code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
cax = plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
plt.show()
```

Doing this for the two examples immediately makes clear that matplotlib.pyplot updates the range of the color-scale to the data. Consequently the conversion betweens colors and numerical values is different for the two cases.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful with the colorbar :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found out that `imshow` does normalize by default, so to avoid this, the `vmin` and `vmax` must be given to `imshow`, which is then:

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=1)
```