# Why is the image stored and show different?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, librosa

I am having some problems saving the image I am displaying as numpy ndarays.

Example:

This code:

```
librosa.display.specshow(static.T,sr=16000,x_axis='frames',y_axis='mel',hop_length=160,cmap=cm.jet)
plt.title("log mel power spectrum of " + name)
plt.colorbar(format='%+02.0f dB')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(plot+"/"+name+"_plot_static_conv.png")
plt.show()
```

Will show an image like this:

[image]

But when i store the image into a numpy ndarray, and then tries to plot it, I get something like this..

```
convert = plt.get_cmap(cm.jet)
numpy_output_static = convert(static.T)
plt.imshow(numpy_output_static)
plt.show()
raw_input("sadas")
```

Show  me an image:

[image]

what is going on?.. why cant i store the same image, and view it the same way?

Minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from PIL import Image
import librosa
import librosa.display
from matplotlib import cm


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
min = -1.828067
max = 22.70058
data =  np.random.uniform(low=min, high=max, size=(474,40))
librosa.display.specshow(data.T,sr=16000,x_axis='frames',y_axis='mel',hop_length=160,cmap=cm.jet)
plt.show()
raw_input("sadas")

convert = plt.get_cmap(cm.jet)
numpy_output_static = convert(data.T)
plt.imshow(numpy_output_static, aspect = 'auto')
plt.show()
raw_input("asds")
```

First plot being :

[image]

Second plot being:

[image]

Normalizing the dataset doesn't fix the second image.

Comment: Please try to come up with a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It most likely has something to do with the limits of the color-axis... You can add a colorbar to find out. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715813/how-to-show-numpy-nxm-array-with-dtype-float-as-plain-gray-scale-image/43716106#43716106)

Comment: Also dB is a logarithmic axis. We can only guess in which units `static` is?????

Comment: Can you please modify your post such that it can be reproduced. I.e. generate static, and modify the images accordingly? Also, have you looked into the color-scale?

Comment: I currently working out an example using the real data.. I tried random values, which it seem to work correctly on.. but on `static` dataset it seem to  mess up..

Comment: @TomdeGeus I've added the exampe.. I tried with added limits.. same results

Comment: Input data is filter energies of 40 filterbanks.

Comment: Thanks. If I were you I'd remove the first half of your question. To be more precise. The horizontal and vertical axes you'll be able with matplotlib (use `extent` for `imshow` and then the usual commands). For the color-index you'll really have to clarify what unit `data` is in, and what conversion `librosa.display.specshow` does. From the documentation it seems that many units can be supplied, so I'm quite sure there is some conversion...

Comment: @TomdeGeus I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821518/matplotlib-save-plot-to-numpy-array

Which seemed  make it possible to save the plot... but the shape of the `numpy.ndarray` don't matches with the original dataset.

Comment: @TomdeGeus According to https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/master/librosa/display.py#L459

Is nothing being done to the data.. only the axis is being adjusted for..

Comment: @TomdeGeus Its just a colormesh.. https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/master/librosa/display.py#L678

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are related to how you use `imshow` (see below for explanation).

### Solution

I have converted your input data from something random to something regular such that the comparison is more straightforward. I get a nicely matching result using the implementation below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import librosa
import librosa.display

data = np.linspace(-1.828067,22.70058,474*40).reshape(474,40)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
librosa.display.specshow(data.T,sr=16000,x_axis='frames',y_axis='mel',hop_length=160,cmap=cm.jet)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
extent = (0,474,0,9325.7)
plt.imshow(data.T,cmap='jet',extent=extent)
ax2.set_aspect(abs((extent[1]-extent[0])/(extent[3]-extent[2]))/4.)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

### Explanation

Now, what went wrong? You used

```
convert = plt.get_cmap(cm.jet)
```

The result `convert` can best be thought of as a list with **256** RGBA color-entries:

```
>>> convert(0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0)

>>> convert(1)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.517825311942959, 1.0)

>>> convert(2)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.535650623885918, 1.0)

...

>>> convert(254)
(0.517825311942959, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

>>> convert(255)
(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Now the trick is that it's a 'special' list, which will just return the maximum when going out of bounds:

```
>>> convert(256)
(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

>>> convert(257)
(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

... 

>>> convert(1000)
(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

This is exactly what happened to you. Your diagram was therefore almost entirely red (the last color of "jet").

Instead, in the code I provided the data is mapped on to the 256 colors (the minimum gets assigned `convert(0)`, the maximum `convert(255)`, or more generally: `(value-min_val)*255/(max_val-min_val)`.

### References

- [Set aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965743/how-can-i-set-the-aspect-ratio-in-matplotlib)

Comment: i am not sure what the answer here is... ? are you saying I should convert the random data into a range of 0  - 255 then cmaps it, and when I then plot the cmapped data it all should be ok?

Comment: I am not sure if this fixes things?.. I don't seem to be able to replicate your results in my usecase.  I still get the a red image, even if I normalize it.. besides that.. What you state could not be the case, as the max value is 22 and not above 255.. so..

Comment: I'm saying that you should have matplotlib do the color mapping, and you shouldn't try to do it manually. So put in the raw data together with the name of the colormap and optionally the limits in `imshow` and let it do its magic. This is the first part of my answer. The second part is just an explanation why your manual mapping was unsuccessful. But again let the library do its thing, that's where is there for.

Comment: Problem is that that the image stored as numpy ndarray is used as a input to a nn, which means representation is important... i need to store the plot as a numpy arrays with each pixel corresponding to pixels in the plot..

Comment: Now I'm really getting confused... Your input is a numpy array and the most accurate representation!? All we've been talking about is repenting visually using colors, for us humans to do something with it.

Comment: Using the colormap was a way of representing the data in a different way such that certain pattern would occur, and could be seen by a neural network. Numpy array I save doesn't resemble the plot i make, causing a problem when i use it as an input for a neural network (not part of this question but related to), as the desired patterns aren't shown in there..