# Black image when image is normalized

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I'm using the following procedure to normalize images by following the tutorial on the TF 2.3 [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images):

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)
normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]
# Notice the pixels values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))
```

But after testing this for training my vision model doesn't converge. It works fine if I don't use the normalization layer but I'm afraid I'm hurting its performance by using non-normalized images. Also, after trying to render the normalized images I see only black images.

I use `imshow` to show the images.

I don't really understand why the images are black when I use `imshow()` and why my model doesn't work with the normalized images

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43716098/6245650

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr interesting, thanks. Then the problem must be with my learning rate.

Comment: Yea, your lr may be too big, especially if your values are normalized between 0 and 1

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr i did try it with like 1e-4 - 1e-6 which i thought would be enough, now im not so sure

Comment: plt.imshow()  or cv2.imshow()  .Your images are  RGB  or gray?

Comment: Wow, that's pretty small for a learning rate. Was your error bouncing around after each epoch or was it just descending really slowly?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr validation loss was oscillating really hard. like it would go from 2.1 to 1800

Comment: @TouYou mostly gray yes i was using  plt.imshow(image) but they are RGB encoded

Comment: your image is a tf.tensor , did you convert it to np.array  :image_batch[0].numpy().